# How do I find out if a multivariate function is multimodal?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, numerical-methods, multilinear-algebra

I have programed a function in Matlab. Trying to optimize it, the local gradient based optimizer fails, while a global one doesn't. I suspect that the function is multimodal and that this is the cause of the failure.
How can I actually determine if a multivariate function is multimodal?

Comment: Sample it at a few points, and see how it looks?

Comment: When I fix all variables except two and make a 3d plot it does not show multimodality for any of the variable pair I have tested. If I look at all possible pairs and no 3d plot is multimodal does this imply that the function is not multimodal?